# How to include rows from a Pandas Dataframe that contain strings from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-mining

I have a Pandas Dataframe.  One of the columns is a string.  It contains a typed report.

The Dataframe is `DF_Check` and the column in question is `DF_Check['COM']`

I would like to return the rows that contain the words from `list1` in `DF_Check['COM']`.  I have a list:

```
list1=['stopped','broken','failure','damaged']
```

Any my current code is:

`DF_Priority=DF_Check[(DF_Check['COM'].str.contains('|'.join(priority))==True)]`.

I have also tried

`DF_Priority=DF_Check[(DF_Check['COM'].str.contains('|'.join(priority)))]`

They both find the rows that I am looking for, but I am also getting rows that do not match my desired criteria.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can just use `~df.COM.isin(list1)`

Comment: Can you post your dataframe head? You'll get a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF_Priority = DF_Check[DF_Check['COM'].str.contains('|'.join(list1))]
```

This should work... if it doesn't then you need to provide data to verify what you are doing.